# How to find out information on client's reads on a named pipe

Tags: windows, winapi, named-pipes

Is it possible to figure out on the writer (server) end of a Windows named pipe how much data the client is reading from the other end in each request?

**Background:** Simple scenario.  We have one process that writes to a named pipe that it creates via [CreateNamedPipe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365150%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  The data only flows outward (PIPE_ACCESS_OUTBOUND) and is PIPE_TYPE_BYTE. Another process reads from the pipe and displays some information about it. This repeats about once per second.

**What I need to change:** I have to add a little bit more data to each write and subsequent read.  This is no problem to update both the client and the server, but the person who created this 14 years ago apparently didn't think the structure of the data in the pipe would ever change.  No metadata is included whatsoever and the client pays no attention to the amount of data available.  For example, let's say the structure size has been 8 bytes for all these years.  The server writes 8 bytes, the client reads 8 bytes.  Now I want to write 12 bytes.  If it is an old client doing the reading, it will get weird results since it just tries to blindly read 8 bytes each time.

**What I currently have working:** I have an ugly solution working now, but am not overly pleased.  I used GetNamedPipeClientProcessId to get the process ID of the reader and then the appropriate calls to get its file name and then version information (OpenProcess, GetModuleFileNameEx, GetFileVersionInfo, ...) to determine the version number of the client and then write the appropriate amount of data. It appears to work, but it feels a bit cumbersome and fragile.

**What I think I want:** What I would like to do is have the server somehow detect that the client only read 8 bytes from the pipe and then adjust the behavior accordingly. Is it possible to figure this out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have some form of handshake on connection from new clients to say "I support XYZ". If you don't get that, keep at the 8 bytes

Comment: +1 That's a good idea and simple too.  I will play around with it today. I was fixated on leaving it as a single direction pipe, but I don't think there are problems using the duplex option.  I'll see.

Comment: I finally got back around to this.  This worked well.  All I had to do was change the pipe type when created (to duplex) and update the client to open the pipe with write access and to write a version value.